# Describing a family of sets with a function

Tags: logic

Let $X$ be a finite set. Let $M \subseteq 2^X$ satisfy the following properties:

**PROPERTY 1:**

If $A \in M$ and $A \subseteq B \subseteq X$ then $B \in M$.

**PROPERTY 2:**

If $A,B,C,D \subseteq X$ satisfy the following conditions:

1. $A \cap B = \emptyset$
2. $C \cap D = \emptyset$
3. $A \cup B \notin M$
4. $A \cup C \in M$
5. $B \cup D \in M$

Then $C \cup D \in M$.

I wonder if it's always possible to find a function $f: X \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ and a number $\varepsilon >0$ such that:

$$M=\{A \subseteq X: \sum_{x \in A}f(x) \geq \varepsilon\}$$

Showing that these properies are neccessary is fairly easy, but I have no clue how to show that they're sufficient.